# Using Open XML to read an Excel spreadsheet, how do I determine the sheet that a Table is on?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

If I have a loaded SpreadsheetDocument instance:

```
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument
```

and iterate over the WorksheetParts:

```
foreach (var wp in spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
```

for every part that is a "Table" I can get to the table definition with:

```
wp.TableDefinitionParts
```

and grab the first entry.  At this point I can grab the table name:

```
var tableName = tableDefinitionPart.Table.Name;
```

But how do I determine which sheet this this table is located in?

Answer (score 0):

Given a `WorksheetPart` (as assigned to `wp` in your code), the first entry `Parts` list will be an `Packaging.IdPartPair` object:

```
var parts = wp.Parts.ToList();
var idPartPair = parts[0];
```

If you take a look at the value of

```
idPartPair.OpenXmlPart.Uri.OriginalString
```

it will be a string that looks like this:

```
/xl/tables/table2.xml
```

The only thing you care about is the number `2` in that string.  Believe it or not, that's actually saying that the table is in the third sheet of the workbook (zero-based)

At this point, write your favorite code to extract the 2 out of the above code.  My version is this, but I'm sure someone else can make this shorter:

```
var sheetNo = int.Parse(string.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(idPartPair.OpenXmlPart.Uri.OriginalString).Skip(5)));
```

Next, get the list of sheets:

```
var sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.ToList();
```

Then use `sheetNo` to index into it:

```
var sheet = (Sheet)sheets[sheetNo];
```

Then you can easily get the sheet name:

```
var sheetName = sheet.Name;
```